# Correct way to parametrize a generic java event handler

Tags: java, generics

I have some code as follows (excerpt):

```
public interface Event<S> {
    S getSource();
}

public interface Subscriber<E> {
    void update(E event);
}

public interface EventPublisher<S, E extends Event<S>> {
    void addSubscription(S source, Subscriber<E> subscriber);
    void removeSubscription(S source, Subscriber<E> subscriber);
}

public class SubscriptionManager<S, E extends Event<S>> implements Subscriber<E>, EventPublisher<S, E> {
    ...
}

public class MyEvent implements Event<MyEventSource> {
    ...
}
```

This all works fine, however, my problem is when I try something like this:

```
public class MyEventHandler {
    private final SubscriptionManager<Class<? extends Event<?>>, ? extends Event<?>> subscriptionManager = new SubscriptionManager<>();

    Subscriber<? extends Event<?>> subscriber = ...;
    subscriptionManager.addSubscription(MyEvent.class, subscriber); **// Compile error**
}
```

I get the following error:

```
The method addSubscription(Class<? extends Event<?>>, Subscriber<capture#3-of ? extends Event<?>>) in the type SubscriptionManager<Class<? extends Event<?>>,capture#3-of ? extends Event<?>> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<MyEvent>, Subscriber<capture#5-of ? extends Event<?>>)
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If you want this sort of reflection-based thing where you pass around `Class` objects, there won't be an alternative to accepting some unsafe casts.

Comment: `SubscriptionManager<Class<? extends Event<?>>, ? extends Event<?>>` here the actual type is unknown and `subscriptionManager.addSubscription(MyEvent.class, subscriber);` here the actual type is unkown. So you have two different captures (not applicable to eachother). `Subscriber<? extends Event<?>> subscriber` should have some concreate type instead of `?`.

Comment: Wouldn't that have caused a compiler error sooner then?  He could be providing a concrete type on the right hand side of the assignment right?

Comment: It should be a compiler error, captures are relevant to compiler only, IMO.

Comment: IMO, it would easier to use some concrete type. Heterogenity and type-safety together at this level is very complex and tricky, IMHO. :)

Answer (score 4):

To be honest with you I think there's some design error in your code. It almost looks like a perfectly designed pattern, but something doesn't add up. You can probably omit half of generic parameters and make it more straightforward.

Please consider the code below. Entire framework is parametrized by a single parameter. Everything compiles and there are no raw types used.
Also, note that MyEvent is never used in the framework definition. It's a convenience class.
You can safely invoke subscriptionManager.update(new MyEvent()); somewhere in your code.

More complicated arrangements are possible too, but I believe that's the one you need.
Please let me know if that works for you.

```
static interface Event<S> {
    S getSource();
}

static interface Subscriber<S> {
    void update(Event<S> event);
}

static interface EventPublisher<S> {
    void addSubscription(Class<S> sourceClass, Subscriber<S> subscriber);
    void removeSubscription(Class<S> sourceClass, Subscriber<S> subscriber);
}

static class SubscriptionManager<S> implements Subscriber<S>, EventPublisher<S> {
    public void addSubscription(Class<S> sourceClass, Subscriber<S> subscriber) {
    }
    public void removeSubscription(Class<S> sourceClass, Subscriber<S> subscriber) {
    }
    public void update(Event<S> event) {
    }
}

static class MyEvent implements Event<String> {
    public String getSource() {
        return null;
    }
}

static class MyEventHandler {
    private final SubscriptionManager<String> subscriptionManager = new SubscriptionManager<String>();
    public MyEventHandler() {
        Subscriber<String> subscriber = null;
        subscriptionManager.addSubscription(String.class, subscriber);
    }
}
```